# iOS cancellable background task implementation

Tags: ios, asynchronous, cancellation

I need a class with a `<foo>` method which executes a background task.

This `<foo>` method is called many times from different threads: each time this method is called, i need to stop the previous allocated background threads and start a new one, so the only valid background task is the last created.

How to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSOperation** class so you can cancel your operation.[Refer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
-(void)startMyOperation
{

    //Cancel the existing operation
    [self cancelOperation];
    self.operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
   //your code to be done in the background
    }];
}

-(void)cancelOperation
{
     if(![self.operaion isFinished])
        [self.operation cancel];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement cancellable operations is to use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. Read the documentation carefully. To create an NSOperation that actually stops doing things when cancelled, the task that the NSOperation performs must actually check from time to time whether it has been cancelled and then stop doing things.

You should probably create a subclass of NSOperation, implement the "start" method, override the "isFinished" method, possibly override the "cancel" method or observe the "isCancelled" property, and when you detect that the operation is cancelled, stop doing things and change the isFinished property in a KVO compatible way (usually by sending willChangeValueForKey: and didChangeValueForKey].

The ASIHttpRequest library does that kind of thing, so it would be a good idea to look at their source code.